# How to remove same property name from sub object and push the sub objects as element of an array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The coursesMarks property is present in every object. So I want to **push the value inside coursesMarks property**, to an array and return the array to the user.

```
[
        {
            "coursesMarks": {
                "_id": "634a9be567a1f07be02f71d8",
                "courseCode": "cse1201",
                "courseTitle": "SP"
            }
        },
        {
            "coursesMarks": {
                "_id": "634a9be567a1f07be02f71db",
                "courseCode": "cse1203",
                "courseTitle": "DS"
                
            }
        }
]
```

Then expected output is:

```
[
{

     "courses":
                {
                        "_id": "634a9be567a1f07be02f71d8",
                        "courseCode": "cse1201",
                        "courseTitle": "SP"
                },
                {
                        "_id": "634a9be567a1f07be02f71db",
                        "courseCode": "cse1203",
                        "courseTitle": "DS"
                }
    
}
]
```

Comment: Does the array that you show there represent two input documents or a single one? If a single one, what's the name of the array in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked a clarifying question in the comments. But if we assume that the sample data provided is a single document where the array is stored in a field named `arr`, then a pipeline similar to the following may be what you are looking for:

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      courses: {
        $map: {
          input: "$arr",
          in: "$$this.coursesMarks"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "arr"
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qJIkirW7oZQ)

---

**Edit**

Based on the additional [information about the structure of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173369/how-to-remove-same-property-name-from-sub-object-and-push-the-sub-objects-as-ele/74174124?noredirect=1#comment130964211_74174124), you are looking to `$group` things in this particular case. Therefore the relevant addition to your pipeline should look something like this:

```
[
  ...
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      courses: {
        $push: "$coursesMarks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  }
]
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v8vR7cnBv8f). It includes an empty `$match` stage at the beginning to represent whatever additional matching logic you currently have.

Comment: The array is not under any field. Let, it is the result of a $match operation in the first stage of aggregation.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer based on that information.